# use row_number() over(partition by col order by col) in where clause

Tags: sql-server, subquery

I have these tables in which I need to use `Row_number()` in `where` clause like this

```
where spectrumcms.staffchilddiscountpolicy.childno =
(select  ROW_NUMBER() Over (Partition by std.GuardianCNIC  order by std.ID ASC))
```

I have tables like these

[image]

Now i have this query

```sql
select
  std.ID as ID,
  std.FirstName,
  std.LastName,
  emp.ID as EmpID,
  emp.FirstName + '' + emp.LastName as EmpName,
  emp.CNIC,
  (
    select count(*) as NoOfChilds
      from StudentManagement.SpectrumCMS.Student stdd
      join HRManagement.SpectrumCMS.Employee empp on stdd.GuardianCNIC = empp.CNIC
      where empp.ID = emp.ID and stdd.CompanyID = std.CompanyID and empp.CompanyID = emp.CompanyID
  ) as NoOfchilds,
  ROW_NUMBER() Over (Partition by std.GuardianCNIC order by std.ID ASC) as ChildNo 

from StudentManagement.SpectrumCMS.Student std
join HRManagement.SpectrumCMS.Employee emp on std.GuardianCNIC = emp.cnic
where std.CompanyID = 20145
  and emp.CompanyID = 20145
  and std.IsActive = 1
  and emp.IsActive = 1
order by emp.CNIC
```

Now coming to main question why I need `where=row_number()over(partition by col order by col)`:

Because i need to get percentage in last column of above mentioned query from the table of which i have posted the picture of.

This is what currently i am getting

[image]

Now in last `percentage` column, I need `percentage` from the `staffchilddiscountpolicy` table of which I have added picture

Comment: Gievn that the `row_number` is partitioned by `GuardianCNIC`, how do you propose to join `staffchilddiscountpolicy.childno` to it, you're going to need another join column. Also you can replace that subquery with `count(*) over (partition by...`

Comment: Hi, and welcome to dba.se! Please avoid using images for the reasons outlined in this [post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557).

Comment: Please construct your questions based on the details in [mcve].   Adding table DDL statements, sample DML statements, and providing desired output via a markup table as shown in the example makes it easier for us to provide great answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you can't use a window function in that capacity. Rather you should take your first query and put it in a subquery or CTE such that you can then join on `ChildNo` between it and the `SpectrumCMS.StaffChildsDiscountPolicy` table like so:

```
WITH CTE_StudentChildNumbers AS
(
    select
        std.ID as ID,
        std.FirstName,
        std.LastName,
        emp.ID as EmpID,
        emp.FirstName + '' + emp.LastName as EmpName,
        emp.CNIC,
        (
            select count(*) as NoOfChilds
            from StudentManagement.SpectrumCMS.Student stdd
            join HRManagement.SpectrumCMS.Employee empp on stdd.GuardianCNIC = empp.CNIC
            where empp.ID = emp.ID 
                and stdd.CompanyID = std.CompanyID 
                and empp.CompanyID = emp.CompanyID
        ) as NoOfchilds,
       ROW_NUMBER() Over (Partition by std.GuardianCNIC order by std.ID ASC) as ChildNo 
   from StudentManagement.SpectrumCMS.Student std
   join HRManagement.SpectrumCMS.Employee emp on  std.GuardianCNIC = emp.cnic
   where std.CompanyID = 20145
       and emp.CompanyID = 20145
       and std.IsActive = 1
       and emp.IsActive = 1
)

SELECT 
    SCN.ID, 
    SCN.FirstName, 
    SCN.LastName, 
    SCN.EmpID, 
    SCN.EmpName, 
    SCN.CNIC, 
    SCN.NoOfchilds, 
    SCN.ChildNo,
    SCDP.Percentage
FROM CTE_StudentChildNumbers AS SCN
INNER JOIN SpectrumCMS.StaffChildsDiscountPolicy SCDP
    ON SCN.ChildNo = SCDP.ChildNo
WHERE SCDP.CompanyID = 20145 -- Not sure if you wanted the same filters from your screenshot, feel free to remove if not needed
    AND SCDP.IsActive = 1 
ORDER BY SCN.CNIC
```

Comment: i did this already but it returns 0 rows

Comment: @learning17 Then the way you're generating `ChildNo` with the `ROW_NUMBER()` window function is possibly incorrect and there are no relating values to it in your `SpectrumCMS.StaffChildsDiscountPolicy` table for the filters you're currently applying to each. Please start by verifying you even get any results for the inner query of the CTE in my example, and go from there by adding or removing the remaining joins and filters to see where the fallout is coming from.

Comment: you are right actually i wanted a way where i could achieve this without using cte but i think thats not possible
your solution works btw so thanks

Comment: @learning17 No problem! I believe you'd either need to use a CTE or a subquery, but I find CTEs more clean / readable, personally.